# React hooks doing an infinite fetching when getting data from child but has no problem if the parent is a class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a reusable SearchHeader component that has a controlled input and passes the data from the input to his parents

> SearchHeader.js

```
const SearchHeader = ({ onChangeSearch }) => {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      onChangeSearch(searchValue);
    }, 400);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    };
  }, [searchValue, onChangeSearch]);
  return (
    <Container>
      <ContainerHead>
        <ContainerInput>
          <IoSearch />
          <div style={{ width: '5px' }}></div>
          <TextInput
            className="TextInput_Search"
            placeholder="Search here..."
            value={searchValue}
            onChange={(evt) => setSearchValue(evt.target.value)}
          />
        </ContainerInput>
        <div style={{ width: '8px' }}></div>
        <Text
          size="12px"
          weight="400"
          color={Token.color.white}
          cursor="pointer"
          onClick={() => history.goBack()}
        >
          Batal
        </Text>
      </ContainerHead>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Everything it's okay when I use this component in-class component to make an API request and set the state for the result

> UniversalSearch.js

```
class UniversalSearch extends Component {
  state = {
    searchResult: [],
  };

  handleSearch = (value) => {
    if (value) {
      universalSearch(value).then((response) => {
        this.setState({ searchResult: response.data });
        console.log(response.data);
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchHeader onChangeSearch={this.handleSearch} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

but when I turn the component into a functional component the handle search won't stop fetching an API request

```
export default function UniversalSearch() {
  const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState([]);
  const handlesearch = (value) => {
    universalSearch(value).then((response) => {
      setSearchResult(response.data)
      console.log(response.data);
    });

  return (
    <div>
      <SearchHeader onChangeValue={handlesearch}/>
     </div>
  );
}
```

the infinite fetching only came when I set the state for the searchResult. but in-class component everything working as expected that make me so confused how it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to happen because every time you set the state value in the function the component renders and creates a new function.

In order to fix this, you can make use of `useCallback`.

```
const handlesearch = useCallback((value) => {
    universalSearch(value).then((response) => {
      setSearchResult(response.data)
      console.log(response.data);
    }), [universalSearch])
```

Comment: well. I'm not explore usecallback that much. but this is works. but I don't really get the real problem of why this Is happen? what  useCallback do ? and when I put universalSearch function as a dependency for useCallback react gives me a warning for unnecessary dependencies.. But thanks it is stopped the infinite fetch now

Comment: I have mentioned the problem above. When in UniversalSearch you do `setSearchResult ` the component renders and you will get a new instance of `handlesearch`,  which you pass in `SearchHeader`, and in `SearchHeader` you have the prop as a dependency, and hence this is called again and again.

When you use `useCallback` it makes sure that the new function instance is created when the dependency changes.